# XMLTYPE update replacing values in last tag in Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle12c, xmltype

I have a XMLTYPE with 3 tag elements of the same name. I want to replace ';' with a '.' in the last one. Something like this:

```
SELECT XMLQUERY (
          'copy $tmp := . modify
            (for $i in $tmp/root/test/text()  
             return replace value of node $i
                    with ''.'') 
            return $tmp'
          PASSING XMLTYPE (
                     '<root><test>asdasdsada;</test><test>lkjasdhalskdjhlakjsdh;</test><test>tirari;</test></root>')
          RETURNING CONTENT)
  FROM DUAL
```

My result shoud be like this;

```
<root><test>asdasdsada;</test><test>lkjasdhalskdjhlakjsdh;</test><test>tirari.</test></root>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment you're modifying all of the `test` nodes, and you are replacing the contents completely with a period. From your expected output that isn't what you want.

You can count the number of `test` nodes into a variable, and then use `[postition()=$n]` to only apply your replace to the final node. You can then use the `replace()` or `translate()` function to only change the `;` to `.`, rather than replacing the entire text content of the node:

```
SELECT XMLQUERY (
          'copy $tmp := . modify
            (let $n := count($tmp/root/test)
            for $i in $tmp/root/test[position()=$n]/text()  
             return replace value of node $i with replace($i, ";", "."))
            return $tmp'
          PASSING XMLTYPE (
                     '<root><test>asdasdsada;</test><test>lkjasdhalskdjhlakjsdh;</test><test>tirari;</test></root>')
          RETURNING CONTENT) AS RESULT
  FROM DUAL;

RESULT                                                                                                                  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<root><test>asdasdsada;</test><test>lkjasdhalskdjhlakjsdh;</test><test>tirari.</test></root>
```

Comment: 2000 points for you!! Thanks. I was unable to get the number of ´test´nodes. And without that I wasn't able to continue the logic... Thanks!